# Fortran Type Operators

Tags: vector, fortran, operator-keyword

I am implementing a vector type and want to have the scalar and vector product operations.

```
Type (Vector) :: va, vb, vc
Real :: c       
c = smul (va, vb)
va = vmul (vb, vc)
c = va .d. vb
va = va .x. vb
```

How can I implement the two operators. I already have the functions.

```
Function vector_smul  &
  (                   &
    va, vb            &
  )                   &
    Result (dotp)

Real :: dotp

Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: va, vb

dotp = (va% u * vb% u) + (va% v * vb% v) + (va% w * vb% w)

End Function vector_smul
```

and

```
Function vector_vmul  &
  (                   &
    va, vb            &
  )                   &
    Result (vc)

  Type (Vector) :: vc

  Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: va, vb

  vc% u = (va% v * vb% w) - (va% w * vb% v)
  vc% v = (va% w * vb% u) - (va% u * vb% w)
  vc% w = (va% u * vb% v) - (va% v * vb% u)

End Function vector_vmul
```

I have tried using generic this way

```
Type :: Vector

  Real :: u
  Real :: v
  Real :: w

  Contains

  Procedure :: smul => vector_smul
  Generic :: Operator (.d.) => smul

  Procedure :: vmul => vector_vmul
  Generic :: Operator (.x.) => vmul

  Procedure :: normal => vector_normal

End Type Vector
```

but getting the error

```
lib/meidum/meidum_vectors.f:253:31:
   Generic :: Operator (.d.) => vector_smul
                           1
Error: Undefined specific binding 'vector_smul' 
as target of GENERIC 'd' at (1)

lib/meidum/meidum_vectors.f:258:31:

Generic :: Operator (.x.) => vector_vmul
                           1
Error: Undefined specific binding 'vector_vmul' 
as target of GENERIC 'x' at (1)
```

I have also another function that returns the normal to two vectors and optionally to three position vectors.

```
Function vector_normal  & 
  (                     &
    va, vb, vc          &
  )                     &
    Result (vn)

Type (Vector) :: vn

Class (Vector), Intent (In) :: va, vb
Class (Vector), Intent (In), Optional :: vc

If (Present (vc)) Then
  Block
    Type (Vector) :: vab, vac
    vab = vb - va
    vac = vc - va
    vn = vector_vmul (vab, vac)
  End Block
 Else
  vn = vector_vmul (va, vb)
End If

vn = vn% unitv ()

End Function vector_normal
```

When I use  `Procedure :: vector_normal` in the `contains` section of the type definition I get the error

```
uts/meidum/test_meidum_vectors.f:1115:12:

    va = normal (vb, vc)
        1
Error: Function 'normal' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
uts/meidum/test_meidum_vectors.f:1123:12:

    va = normal (va, vb, vc)
        1
Error: Function 'normal' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Comment: Does your type `contain` those procedures?

Comment: Yes, the `procedure` and `generic` calls are included in the contains section of `Type (Vector)`.

Comment: Can you show how you define the type?

Comment: What compiler are you using? This exact code works fine with both gfortran 4.8.2 and ifort 15 for me.

Comment: I assume everything is in the same module and everything has an explicit interface. That's the only thing I can think of barring a compiler error.

Comment: When I use `vector_smul` and `vector_vmul` I do not get the error messages